# Numpy 2d array extrude

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am new to numpy ndarrays and i couldn`t find any solution for my issue.
I have say 10 files of floating point data. I apply some operation for every pair of files, that returns 1D array.

What I want is to have block matrix A[10x10] with rows and cols are my ten files and every element in that matrix is block of 1D array that results my operation applied to f_i and f_j.

I gues i need some kind of map, so that i could tell "This f_i and f_j result in certain array" and could access this array by f_i, f_j.

What would be the best way to achive this? Endpoint of that task is to output this matrix into csv file.

Data schema:

[image: data schema]

Comment: I think it might be better if you give an example with some sample data. Right now it is not completely clear what you aim to do.

Comment: Added picture representing my issue in EDIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can accomplish your goal just using a nested list (https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
# build a 10x10 matrix with default value 0
matrix = [[0 for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
# assign the result to a cell
matrix[1][1] = ['result', 'of', 'some', 'operation']
# retrieve the result
print (matrix[1][1])
#=> ['result', 'of', 'some', 'operation']
```

Comment: Thanks for that advice, it seems to work. Guess i just i got confused that using np.ndarrays in my previous calculations means i have to use it till the very end)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `np.append` method in numpy.
You can check the details in [numpy.append](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

Comment: I need to insert at certain index, not at the end

Comment: I see. Then you can try a 3-d dataframe. But it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this pretty cleanly with a dictionary like so:

```
file_pairs_table = {}
file_a = "file_a.txt"
file_b = "file_b.txt"
file_pairs_table[(file_a,file_b)] = np.arange(999) #operation resulting in 1d array here.
```

Then access the value of the file pair like this:

```
file_pairs_table[(file_a,file_b)]
>>> array([0,1,...,998])
```